# filter syntax where some items may or may not be selected

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, code-behind

I've got 3 dropdown boxes on my asp.net form: Country, State and City.  I want to use these to filter my data.  However, I also want the user to have the ability to not use the filters, or not use *all* the filters.

For instance, they may not want to filter at all.  Or they may only want to filter by Country.  Or only by Country/State.  Or, if it's not the US, then by Country/City.

I'm stuck on how to write this.  Right now I have:

```
 SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [MOS_Role] where [Country_ID] = @CoID AND [State_ID] = @StID AND [City_ID] = @CiID ORDER BY [Role] ASC", con2);
 adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoID", Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedValue));
 adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StID", Convert.ToInt32(ddlState.SelectedValue));
 adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CiID", Convert.ToInt32(ddlCity.SelectedValue));
```

but that doesn't work when you leave a dropdown unselected.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query which will help you

```
Select * from [MOS_Role]
where ([Country_ID] = @CoID OR @CoID IS NULL)
AND ([State_ID] = @StID OR @StID IS NULL)
AND ([City_ID] = @CiID OR @CiID IS NULL)
ORDER BY [Role] ASC
```

You should pass as parameter selected value or `null` if not selected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if it's empty first, then add. Do this for each `AddWithValue` call:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ddlCountry.SelectedValue))
    adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoID", Convert.ToInt32(ddlCountry.SelectedValue));
```